# Failed to decode downloaded font on expressJS/NodeJS

Tags: css, node.js, express, fonts

I have the error such as

```
2localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:9000/fonts/Gotham-Bold.otf
2localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:9000/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf
2localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:9000/fonts/Gotham-Medium.otf
2localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:9000/fonts/GothamRnd-Bold.otf
2localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:9000/fonts/Gotham-Book.otf
```

even though it says 200 OK on the server.

I am using NodeJS and ExpressJS on the backend.

When I just open an index.html with css linked to the font. it works just fine.

```
Here is the request response information:
Remote Address:[::1]:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/fonts/Gotham-Bold.otf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Response Headers
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Mon, 08 Jun 2015 18:41:29 GMT
ETag:"9226-1433787686000"
Last-Modified:Mon, 08 Jun 2015 18:21:26 GMT
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:connect.sid=s%3AkxBebHQL5GFXk6Fjm8zun7fu.F%2FK57o6MZr2wQx1lwxPlp1CCiXxpm4%2BSEdBlO%2FHifss
Host:localhost:9000
If-Modified-Since:Mon, 08 Jun 2015 18:21:26 GMT
If-None-Match:"9226-1433787686000"
Referer:http://localhost:9000/app/app.css
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Not sure how to help... you haven't shown us any relevant code, nor even the actual HTTP response request/response headers.  You're probably sending the wrong `content-type` headers.

Comment: hi Brad. how do you check you are sending wrong content-type headers? I only have this in my expressJS for my static files
     app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));

Comment: I don't see a `Content-Type` header, which will be needed.  Are you sure that is all of your response headers?

Comment: How do you add content-type header? sorry for the newb question.  I am using ExpressJS as the backend server framework.  I thought it is automatically done by the express.static

Comment: It should be automatically done with `express.static()`, that's what's weird about the response above.  It should handle all of that for you, but there is a chance it doesn't understand the font types and is returning `application/octet-stream` for them.  We would need to see what your browser says the `Content-Type` header is, and it's not listed above.

Comment: any leads then? I tried just a regular plain express app, and it worked, but not with the app that i have now

Comment: Post the full response headers.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out why.  the route that called the fonts did not go through express.static.  Now it worked!

Comment: That's why you should post your code.  We may have been able to help you with that.

Comment: @Brad Where does one find the full response headers?

Comment: @AgentZebra The browser's development tools will have them.  You can also use a tool like Fiddler, or even Wireshark to ensure you're seeing what's actually happening over the wire.

Comment: @Brad, thanks. In Chrome Developer tools, where are they? I cannot find :(

Comment: @AgentZebra https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network